# Storm worker connections

Tags: java, linux, apache-storm

I have a strange issue. I use apache 0.10.0 storm version and 3.5.1 zookeeper version. I have 4 different vms on the same network.

I start:

zookeeper at localhost:2181, 1st vm(ip XXX.XXX.5.60)

nimbus & ui, 2nd vm(ip XXX.XXX.5.61)

supervisor 1 on 3rd vm and supervisor 4 on 4th vm(ips XXX.XXX.5.67 & XXX.XXX.5.68).

This is the storm.yaml of the Nimbus:

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
- "XXX.XXX.5.60"
nimbus.host: "XXX.XXX.5.61"
storm.local.dir: "/home/stresstest/data"
```

This is the storm.yaml of the supervisors:

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
- "XXX.XXX.5.60"
nimbus.host: "XXX.XXX.5.61"
storm.local.dir: "/home/stresstest/data"
supervisor.slots.ports:
- 6700
```

As I saw zookeeper accepted the connections normally:

> 2015-11-27 04:16:06,438 [myid:] - INFO 
>   [SyncThread:0:ZooKeeperServer@678] - Established session
>   0x1000000d4ad000b with negotiated timeout 20000 for client
>   /XXX.XXX.5.67:41315 2015-11-27 04:16:06,439 [myid:] - INFO 
>   [SyncThread:0:ZooKeeperServer@678] - Established session
>   0x1000000d4ad000c with negotiated timeout 20000 for client
>   /XXX.XXX.5.68:59833

As you see above each supervisor has 1 worker. From UI's site I see that I have 2 Supervisors and 2 Total slots. When I submit a topology to Nimbus it consumes 1 worker.

And the problem begins here. When I rebalance the topology to consume 2 workers it does this:

> Id    Host    Uptime  Slots   Used slots  Version
>
> b38878ae-8eea-4265-9c98-2b6db1ef0bb0  vlan5-dhcp105.xxx.gr    18m 31s     1
>     1   0.10.0
>
> d463df62-5d18-460f-86f4-18dff93f544a  vlan5-dhcp105.xxx.gr
>     13m 55s     1   1   0.10.0

It appears that the topology uses 2 workers but its the same one.
Worker host appears to be the same for both of the workers/supervisors. So when I send data to Nimbus, only 1 worker is processing and the other one is waiting for data(both workers have downloaded the topology). Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this. Both supervisors had the same hostname (it was passed through the initialization of Xen Hypervisor), so I believe that the vms were conflicted by each other. When I changed one vm's hostname it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of problem in our project and the finding is that, we cannot increase the number of workers by re-balancing command . Re-balancing is only used to decrease the number of workers we use. for example, in the Topology Launcher , provide the Number of worker as 2 , and u can re-balance the topology to 1 worker using re-balance -n 1 command. Also Number of parallelism hint(executors) can be increased or decreased using re-balance command.

Comment: I think that asynchronous re-balance of a topology is a crucial feature of storm. I ran the same topology on Azure (with same number of  virtual machines) and it run pretty smooth.

Comment: @ΒασιληςΙωσηφιδης Hi, Are you using Java or any other language. It seems like we are on the same track.

Answer (score 0):

May be that is because of using same storm.local.dir path for nimbus and supervisor just change the path in your supervisors use different paths and  try for rebalance it I think it will work.